# Performance using OpenMP doesn't increase beyond 2 threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp

I've created an implementation of the naive N-body problem with N^2 time complexity using c++ and I've tried to parallelize it using OpenMP. For example, running the program 5 times with 1000 bodies, 100 timesteps, I get the median time taken to execute at 14.06565 seconds. Then running this program with 2 threads with same parameters, I get the median of 6.25671 seconds which is very good (almost even too good since the performance has more than doubled). Although when I try to run the program with 3 threads, I get the median of 6.90014 seconds, which isn't an improvement at all compared to running it with 2 threads. And same thing for when running with 4 threads, I get the median of 7.66918 seconds, and going beyond 4 threads nothing seems to improve.

Now I'm running the program on an AMD ryzen 5 3600 CPU which has more than enough cores to handle more than 4 threads running simultaneously. So I can't pinpoint what is wrong with my code, since previously working with OpenMP, I've never witnessed that only running 2 threads on a program yields the best possible results and more than doubles the speedup. I feel that something may be wrong with my code and I can't pinpoint what exactly, and any help is appreciated. I've tried modifying/changing the scheduling clause for the OMP directives, temporarily removed variables/arrays which may have false sharing (the 2d vector f is a potential candidate for this), and even commented out the moveBodies-function, with the performance being exactly the same. It seems that the issue seems to lie at calculateForces function, perhaps load balancing?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
#include <omp.h>

using namespace std;

struct point{
    double x=0;
    double y=0;

    point(double x_, double y_) : x(x_), y(y_) {}

    point() : x(0), y(0) {}
};

double G = 6.67e-11; //gravity

#define DT 0.01
#define SIZE 9e7


//Generate random double
double fRand(double fMin, double fMax) {
    double f = (double)rand() / RAND_MAX;
    return fMin + f * (fMax - fMin);
}


//calculate total force for every pair of bodies
void calculateForces(vector<point>& p, vector<vector<point>>& f, vector<double>& m, const int& n){
    double distance;
    double magnitude;
    point direction;

    #pragma omp parallel for schedule(static, 1) //Stripes evenly distributed
    for (int i=0; i<n-1;i++){
        int id = omp_get_thread_num();
        for (int j = i+1; j < n; j++) {
            distance =  sqrt(pow((p[i].x - p[j].x),2) + pow((p[i].y - p[j].y),2));
            magnitude = (G*m[i]*m[j]) / pow(distance,2);
            direction.x = p[j].x-p[i].x; 
            direction.y = p[j].y-p[i].y;

            f[id][i].x = f[id][i].x + magnitude*direction.x/distance;

            f[id][j].x = f[id][j].x - magnitude*direction.x/distance;

            f[id][i].y = f[id][i].y + magnitude*direction.y/distance;
            
            f[id][j].y = f[id][j].y - magnitude*direction.y/distance;
        }
    }
}

//calculate new velocity and position for each body
void moveBodies(vector<point>& p, vector<vector<point>>& f, vector<double>& m, vector<point>& v, const int& n) {
    point deltav; // dv=f/m * DT
    point deltap; // dp=(v+dv/2) * DT

    #pragma omp parallel for private(deltav, deltap) schedule(static, 1)
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        point force;
        for (int k = 0; k < omp_get_num_threads(); k++) {
            force.x += f[k][i].x; f[k][i].x = 0;
            force.y += f[k][i].y; f[k][i].y = 0;
        }
        deltav.x = force.x/m[i] * DT;
        deltav.y = force.y/m[i] * DT;
        deltap.x = (v[i].x + deltav.x/2) * DT;
        deltap.y = (v[i].y + deltav.y/2) * DT;
        v[i].x = v[i].x + deltav.x;
        v[i].y = v[i].y + deltav.y;
        p[i].x = p[i].x + deltap.x;
        p[i].y = p[i].y + deltap.y;
        force.x = force.y = 0.0; // reset force vector
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    if (argc != 4) {
        cout << "Incorrect amount of arguments!" << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    srand(time(NULL));

    int gnumBodies = atoi(argv[1]);
    int numSteps = atoi(argv[2]);
    int nThreads = atoi(argv[3]);

    cout << "number of bodies: " << gnumBodies << endl;
    cout << "number of timesteps: " << numSteps << endl;

    omp_set_num_threads(nThreads);

    vector<point> p; //Position
    vector<point> v; //velocity
    vector<vector<point>> f(nThreads, vector<point>(gnumBodies)); //force
    vector<double> m; //mass

    for (int i = 0; i < gnumBodies; i++) {
        p.push_back(point(fRand(0, SIZE), fRand(0, SIZE)));
        v.push_back(point(0,0));
        m.push_back(fRand(6e22, 2e30));
    }

    auto start = omp_get_wtime();
    for (int i=0; i<numSteps; i++){
        calculateForces(p, f, m, gnumBodies);
        moveBodies(p, f, m, v, gnumBodies);
    }

    cout << "Time taken was " << (omp_get_wtime() - start)<< " s"<< endl;
}
```

Comment: For the example mentioned above, 1000 bodies. However the same issue persists if we run with, say, 100 bodies over 1000 timesteps. Time taken then for 1 thread is 1.43791 s. Time taken for 2 threads is 0.603515 s, and time taken for 4 threads is 0.736602 s.

Comment: Why do you use `schedule(static, 1)` ? This seems a particularly bad idea due to *false-sharing* and *NUMA effects*, especially on your processor. Why not just `schedule(static)`? Besides, `vector<vector<point>>` is a really inefficient data structure. Please use two flatten arrays instead (and reading [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AoS_and_SoA)) so your compiler can generate a significantly more efficient assembly code. The trick with `omp_get_thread_num()` is certainly not efficient either. You can certainly use a *private* OpenMP variable or a *thread-local* one.

Comment: The `for (int k = 0; k < omp_get_num_threads(); k++)` loop will certainly not be efficient when the number of thread is large. Please consider switching the two loops (i and k). This might means that two parallel for are needed. But in practice such a loop (accumulating values of 2 arrays) should be memory bound and not scale well. The part that should scale is `calculateForces`.

Comment: @JérômeRichard I agree that `static,1` is not a good idea, but the OP is trying to account for the fact that the inner iterations as `int j = i+1; j < n; j++` so they get shorter. Suggestion: use `guided` schedule.

Comment: You use `int j = i+1; j < n; j++` for the inner loop, which is great from a point of saving operations. However, if you compute the full `i,j` space your code becomes simpler and you can even collapse tthe two loops so that you get a larger iteration space to parallelize. Could be that wasting a little work actually makes your code faster.

Comment: Ha, good point. In that case, the best solution is generally to compute the values by pairs (`i` and `n-2-i` here) so to load balance the computation on all thread. This is generally significantly better than guided since the load-balancing is static so it has (nearly) no overhead. One need to care about the item in the middle that needs not to be computed twice (especially not by two threads).

Comment: Please note that there are data races occurring with the variables `distance`, `magnitude`, and `direction`. This is not only bad to performance, but it also results in undefined behavior. To prevent this, it is recommended to declare these variables within the parallel region (i.e make them private).

Comment: That seemed to have solve it! I used an old matrix class I created in c++ awhile ago which  is stored as an elongated array in memory. Aswell as with the distance, magnitude and direction variables that I completely forgot about, I thought I had declared them private in the OMP header! Now the speedup is alot more understandable after these fixes. 1 thread takes 1.48667 s, 2 threads take 1.01732 s, 3 threads take 0.795577 s and lastly 4 threads take 0.661609 s, thanks!